# How to execute a script on a child html file that is included in the parent's html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am prototyping `Reactjs` into an existing `jQuery project`.

Within the index.html, I am loading a separate html file inside a tab.

```
<div class="tab-content">
        ...
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="golden-records">...</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#golden-records").load("golden-records.html");
    });
</script>
```

Now inside the golden-records.html I have a simple component:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/jsx">

    var SearchForm = React.createClass({
        handleSubmit: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        },
        render: function () {
            return (
                    <form className="searchForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter SID" ref="sid"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
                    </form>
            );
        }
    });

    React.render(
            <SearchForm />,
            document.getElementById('content')
    );

</script>
```

However this component doesn't appear.  It seems the reason is that the script on this html has not run.   How can I make sure this script has run after it's html has loaded? Thanks

Comment: Do you have `<script src="build/react.js"></script>` and `<script src="build/JSXTransformer.js"></script>` in your `golden-records.html`?

Answer (score 1):

React only transpiles and executes `<script type="text/jsx">` elements' contents at loadtime, so it won't act on the newly-added elements introduced with your `$load`.

If you review [JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js](http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js), you'll notice `transformCode` only gets invoked once in `run`, `run` only gets invoked once in `loadScripts`, and `loadScripts` only gets invoked once in `runScripts`. Lastly, `runScripts` is called once on the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

As I see it, you have two options:

1. [Pre-compile JSX.](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx)
2. Use JSXTransformer's `exec`. `JSXTransformer` is a global object exported by the transpiler. Use `JSXTransformer.exec` on your JSX code. You'll need to scrape the `<script type="text/jsx">` elements from your AJAX request and pass its contents to this function. [See this JSFiddle for proof of concept.](http://jsfiddle.net/w7L0s1o3/)